# Collapsed chip display

Tags: flutter, chips

I'm looking for the way to create a row or wrap with chips, but need it works like this:
[image]

I mean if there is no space the chips should be collapsed into container with number of the hidden chips.
Probably there is an existing solution in Flutter or is there any lib for that?

Comment: What are "chips"?

Comment: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Chip-class.html

Comment: Are you looking for the Wrap widget? https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Wrap-class.html.

Comment: No, there is no collapsing feature in Wrap

Comment: It depends on how much chip you like to show, are you trying to hide them all only by showing 1st and 2nd chip?

Comment: I think I should create the package for this.

Comment: Yeasin Sheikh, I need them collapsed only if there is no space, the number can be any. Also if we have 1st chip too long than it should be shown with overflow (...) and others should be collapsed